# Difference between Huawei ID login and Huawei account login using authentication service?

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services

I'm still learning about huawei login and authentication. I've tried login using huawie id with account kit. What I've notice was it will also automatically login to your app gallery. And it also required HMS Core to be installed first. Haven't try using authentication service though. Is there a difference between them? I know that huawei auth service is almost the same as firebase auth.

Comment: Are you asking the difference between  **Authorization Code** and **ID Token** login？

Comment: @shirley Sorry I'm new to this. I followed this tutorial [Link](https://medium.com/huawei-developers/hms-account-kit-with-provider-pattern-in-flutter-bf63981edf63) . Is this different from login using authentication service? The one that has huawei login, facebook, email/pass etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What are the differences and relationships between Auth Service and HUAWEI Account Kit?**

HUAWEI [Account Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050048870?ha_source=hms1) is designed to enable users to sign in to your apps or games freely using HUAWEI IDs.

With [Auth Service](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-auth-introduction-0000001053732605?ha_source=hms1), you can quickly build a secure and reliable user authentication system with very little cost.

**The two services do not conflict with each other.**

Auth Service can connect to multiple third-party authentication systems, including HUAWEI Account Kit, to allow your users to sign in to your apps and games using various authentication modes, including HUAWEI ID.

For Detail,pls kindly refer [FAQs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-auth-faq-0000001053333997#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001072468611__section1358483715447?ha_source=hms1).

Hope it is clear to explain like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

In regards to login, the Account Kit exclusively handles Huawei ID whereas the Auth Service handles both Huawei ID and 3rd party login methods. You can check the documentation for a full list of supported 3rd party login options.

Account Kit: [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050048870)

Auth Service: [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-auth-introduction-0000001053732605)